# Cassandra input mismatch

Tags: python, cassandra

My table in cassandra is:

```
CREATE TABLE cpe (
   ip inet PRIMARY KEY,
   cpe frozen<map<text, frozen<list<text>>>>
);
```

My Table already has a few elements in it, I am trying to select based on IP but I keep getting the error

`mismatched input '.' expecting EOF (... from cpe where ip=10.240[.]...)">`

My Python code looks like this at the moment:

```
rows = session.execute('SELECT ip,cpe from analysis limit 1000')

for i in rows:
   cpe=session.execute('select cpe from cpe where ip='+str(i.ip)) #Error  here
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just in case anyone else runs into the same problem

`cpe=session.execute('select cpe from cpe where ip='+"'"+i.ip+"'")`  should work